# JMeter: Share CSV records between threads

Tags: java, jmeter

I am having a .csv file with 20 records.
[image]

My intention is to read 5 records in a second. So all the 20 records are completed in 4 seconds.
Execution must stop when all the records are read.

**CSV Data Config**
[image]

**Thread Group**
[image]

**Sampler**
[image]

While running it is picking up only few records and each of them is shared between the threads

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason for using `log.info()` and not [__log()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__log) or [__logn()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn) functions?

Now serious: don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, either use "Parameters" section or code-based equivalents instead.

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script **code as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

[image]

and the same but with the code:

[image]

in the above example `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) and `vars` is for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)

Comment: "Any reason for using log.info() and not __log() or __logn() functions?"  -- I am new to jmeter. Basically trying to replicate what is there in java/javascript :)